# scrlttr2 - Change vertical height of header on second page for multiline subject

Tags: vertical-alignment, scrlttr2, footer

I want to use a multiline subject in `scrlttr2` and want to update the vertical distance on the second page between the headerline and the text.

With one line it looks like this:
[image: One line]

With two lines it looks like this:
[image: Two lines]

How is it possible to adjust the vertical distance between the line and the text? It should be equivalent between both screenshots.

If you need an MWE, let me know and I will add one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `headlines=2.1` to the class options.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[headsepline,
  headlines=2.1% <- 
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setkomavar{fromname}{It is me}
\setkomavar{subject}{One Line\\Second Line}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{xxx}
\opening{Hello,}
\Blindtext
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```